# timezone_name_from_abbr fails with 30 minute offset

Tags: php, timezone

I've been trying to get a timezone name based on a provided UTC offset, but I cannot seem to get it working for 30 min offsets (ie [UTC+09:30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B09:30))

```
<?php
function timeZoneTest($input) {
    if ($returnValue = timezone_name_from_abbr('', 60 * 60 * $input, 0)) {
     return $returnValue;
    } else {
     return 'Time Zone Not Found';
    }
}

echo timeZoneTest(9) . '<br>';
echo timeZoneTest(9.5) . '<br>';
```

This returns:

```
Asia/Tokyo
Time Zone Not Found
```

Shouldn't 9.5 return `Australia/Adelaide` or at least a valid php timezone? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
<?php

function tz_offset_to_name($offset)

{
        $offset *= 3600; // convert hour offset to seconds
        $abbrarray = timezone_abbreviations_list();
        foreach ($abbrarray as $abbr)
        {
                foreach ($abbr as $city)
                {
                        if ($city['offset'] == $offset)
                        {
                                return $city['timezone_id'];
                        }
                }
        }

        return FALSE;
}

echo tz_offset_to_name(9) . '<br>';
echo tz_offset_to_name(9.5) . '<br>';

?>
```

**The result will be:**

```
Asia/Tokyo
Australia/Adelaid
```

**DEMO**

https://repl.it/EBSO/0

**---**

> timezone_name_from_abbr() sometimes returns FALSE instead of an actual
>   timezone: http://bugs.php.net/44780

Comment: This works, thanks!
Although it does produce some odd results (-10,-9,-8 all return @America/Anchorage@.
I wasn't anticipating that different UTC offsets would return the same timezone name, but this makes sense due to daylight savings time. I will be re-thinking how I approach the larger problem due to this.
Also, the bug you linked to has been closed and "fixed" a long time ago...